# HD4570 Mobility reports OpenGL 3.0 but in spec OpenGL 3.2

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, opengl, ati-mobility-radeon

I just updated my drivers to 11-12_mobility_vista_win7_32-64_ccc.exe.

I than checked it with OpenGL Extensions Viewer and I see that my card is 100% OpenGL 3.0 and only 60% OpenGL 3.2.

In the spec it says OpenGL 3.2:
http://www.amd.com/us/products/notebook/graphics/ati-mobility-hd-4000/hd-4500/Pages/hd-4500-specs.aspx

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching AMD/ATI site I decided to download the catalyst_mobility_64-bit_util.exe and finally I am reported to support OpenGL 3.2

In Short:
Instead of downloading the Individual Download section I downloaded the file(1.1MB) in the AMD Catalyst Packages section.

Don't really understand why they don't install it with the normal drivers, but...